# How to show/hide JPanel on top of another JPanel in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a main frame which regroup some JPanels. My JFrame is completely filled.

I want to be able to show/hide a small JPanel on top of another JPanel in my JFrame at the left. This JPanel is a configuration area for the user.

So here is my question, **what is the best way to display a JPanel in a small area, on top of everything else, in my JFrame** ?

I tried this but it's not working as expected (this is the code which is executed on click on the settings icon):

```
private void jLabelSettingsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    settingsActive = !this.jLabelEmargement.isVisible();        
    if(!settingsActive){
        FSettings.setSize(222, 380);
        FSettings.setLocation(0, 150);
        FSettings.setVisible(true);
        FSettings.setBackground(new Color(226,236,241));
        this.add(FSettings,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.frameLearners.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelEmargement.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelFinalEval.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelLeaners.setVisible(false);
    }
    else{
        FSettings.setVisible(false);
        this.frameLearners.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelEmargement.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelFinalEval.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelLeaners.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try working with Layered Panes [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: @brainiac080195 Well, didn't know that, I will give it a try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [brainiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859317/brainiac080195) I came up with this as a solution, and it's working as expected:

```
public void toggleSettings(){
    if(this.jLabelEmargement.isVisible()){
        // Set size of JPanel
        FSettings.setSize(222, 380);
        // Set location of JPanel
        FSettings.setLocation(0, 150);
        // Show JPanel
        FSettings.setVisible(true);
        FSettings.setBackground(new Color(226,236,241));
        // Add JPanel to LayeredPane
        jLayeredPaneSettings.add(FSettings, new Integer(5));
        this.frameLearners.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelEmargement.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelFinalEval.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelLeaners.setVisible(false);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/images/cog_00997d_28.png"));
        jLabelSettings.setIcon(icon);
    }
    else{
        // Hide JPanel
        FSettings.setVisible(false);
        // Remove from LayeredPane
        jLayeredPaneSettings.remove(FSettings);
        this.frameLearners.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelEmargement.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelFinalEval.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelLeaners.setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/images/cog_000000_28.png"));
        jLabelSettings.setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

You just have to put **all the components** you want to hide/show in a `LayeredPane`.

Comment: Frankly, the `glassPane` would be simpler

Comment: `JFrame` already has `JLayeredPane`, of which the `glassPane` is part of, while it might "work", I would argue that it's viable solution, but it's you problem to deal with, not mine

Answer (score 2):

You can overlay your frame content with a glasspane.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrateuseofGlassPane.htm

```
JFrame myFrame = ...

JComponent glassPane = new JPanel(null);
myFrame.setGlassPane(glassPane);

private void jLabelSettingsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    settingsActive = !this.jLabelEmargement.isVisible();        
    if(!settingsActive){
        FSettings.setSize(222, 380);
        FSettings.setLocation(0, 150);
        FSettings.setBackground(new Color(226,236,241));
        glassPane.add(FSettings);
        this.frameLearners.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelEmargement.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelFinalEval.setVisible(false);
        this.jLabelLeaners.setVisible(false);
    }
    else{
        glassPane.remove(FSettings);
        this.frameLearners.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelEmargement.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelFinalEval.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabelLeaners.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am using this to show effects or markers inside of a `JFrame`.

Comment: You may need to use `revalidate` and `repaint` on the containers you are changing

Comment: @HJerem try to call setSize() and setLocation() after you added FSettings to the glasspane.